# MDX driven QueryTable returns no rows

Tags: excel, vba, ssas, mdx

I'm using Excel 2007 and [this](http://bit.ly/ximX5X) method to populate a querytable with and MDX query.  When I run the MDX query in BIDS I get a normal result (7x2 result set).  However, when I use it in the QueryTable, I only get two column headers (no results).
**Can anyone tell me why the results aren't being returned to the QueryTable?**

### MDX Query:

```
SELECT
  NULL ON 0
 ,NonEmptyCROSSJOIN([Item].[Company].CHILDREN
 ,[Item].[Division].CHILDREN) ON ROWS
FROM
  [PETE];
```

### Result in QueryTable:

Column Header 1:  [Item].[Company].[Company].[MEMBER_CAPTION]
Column Header 2:  [Item].[Division].[Division].[MEMBER_CAPTION]

### Results in BIDS:

Company1   Division1
Company1   Division2
Company1   Division3
etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange the 'NULL ON 0' -> '{} on 0' is a bit more MDX but I don't think it's the problem. It's looks like a way to switch columns and rows, my educated guess is the issue is you've no data columns.

If you get rid of this or change with a dummy [Measures].defaultmember member, what do you get in Excel ?

Comment: Well, that was it.  For some reason the connection won't return the result of the other.
Unfortunately, I really just want the dimensions in this case.  It works in BIDS.  Why the difference?  More importantly, is there a way to return just the dimensions without a measure?

P.S.  I'll give you the answer regardless of this, but hoping for a little more help fron you or someone else, so I don't want to close it yet.

Comment: You can use calculated members to get member names as a measure (e.g. WITH MEMBER CompanyName AS [Item].[Company].currentmember.name and after play a bit with the vb code. To get the list of members you've to use DISCOVER instead of EXECUTE and I don't know how to do this with VB ..

Comment: I know I haven't answer your question properly, hope I help you nonetheless